# Как отключить автоматическую генерацию колонок в DesignTime у DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Напрягает автоматическая генерация колонок именно в **DesignTime**. По-моему, происходит это только у тех `DataGridView`, для которых настроен `DataSource` на `Detail` таблицу.

Схема такая главная `DataGridView` в источнике данных имеет master `BindingSource`, который привязан к таблице в `DataSet`, `detail` `DataGridView` привязан к master `Bindingsource`, `DataMember` - отношение (master-detail из `DataSet`).

Так вот в непонятные моменты в придачу к столбцам, созданным вручную добавляются все столбцы из связанной таблицы.

Answer (score 1):

Когда создаете столбец вручную в `DataGridView` его нужно привязывать к источнику. Вот ссылка на документацию как это сделать [`DataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.datapropertyname(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Видимо, Вы не поняли вопроса. Я создаю столбцы вручную. Вопрос не в том, как привязать данные к ним. Дело в том, что в режиме проектирования формы (DesignTime) грид сам по себе добавляет все колонки из источника данных. Допустим, у меня есть 3 столбца A, B, C. Мне нужно привязать два из них B и С, что я и делаю. Спустя некоторое время грид сам добавляет еще один набор из всех. В итоге я имею B,C(которые были),A,B,C(которые добавил сам грид.

Comment: Я как понимаю у вас в DataGridView включено авто создание колонок, его можно отключить через свойство AutoGenerateColumns поставив значение false

Comment: Автосоздание отключается в Runtime и никак не влияет на DesignTime